# How to Wait till all files are deleted by my java function?

Tags: java, delete-file, reboot

I am having a problem.
I have a function to remove some files and then reboot the system. It contains a lot of files, so before the whole set of files are getting deleted, my reboot command is getting executed.

How can I solve this in my Java code.

To delete the files, I am using:

```
Runtime.exec("/bin/rm -rf /myDir");
Runtime.exec("/bin/shutdown -r now");
```

Comment: There is nothing here that formats the hard disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Process` returned by `exec` and wait until it finishes:

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("/bin/rm -rf /myDir");
p.waitFor();
Runtime.exec("/bin/shutdown -r now");
```

Comment: If you `waitFor` the machine to reboot, it may not be doing what you think it is. ;)

Comment: The idea was to wait for rm command to finish, to be able to properly launch shutdown. The proposed solution will work, since shutdown is only sending a signal, it will not block until the host is down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process.waitFor() to wait for the command to complete or you could do it all in one.

```
Runtime.exec("/bin/sh -c '/bin/rm -rf /myDir ; /bin/shutdown -r now'");
```

Comment: I cant understand how this solve my problem? Could you please explain this to me. when i tried man sh i dint get much info on waiting for this to complete.

Comment: `sh` is the basic shell. `bash` is Bourne Again SHell which is an extension of it.  It works by running the `rm` and when that finishes, running the `shutdown` i.e. Your Java program doesn't need to do the waiting.

Comment: What if is have this shutdown command in another java function. In that case, do i have to do like Runtime.exec("/bin/sh -c '/bin/rm -rf /myDir'"); and then call the function which does the shutdown?

Comment: If they are separate Java commands, you will need to either create a combined command or use waitFor() on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime.exec methods returns a Process on which you can call [the waitFor method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Do it for the first command and launch the second one just after.